# Can't install anything on ubuntu 14.04 nor updates

Tags: grub2, apt, package-management, themes, dpkg

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 

(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15% 
(Reading database ... 20% 
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 420496 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate_0.3.6~trusty4_all.deb ...
Unpacking grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate (0.3.6~trusty4) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate_0.3.6~trusty4_all.deb (--unpack):    
 trying to overwrite '/boot/grub/themes/ubuntu-mate/background.png', which is also in package grub-theme-ubuntu-mate 0.3.3~trusty1    
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate_0.3.6~trusty4_all.deb    
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-mate-core:
 ubuntu-mate-core depends on grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate; however:
  Package grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate is not installed.    
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-mate-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

when i do this : `sudo apt-get purge grub-theme-ubuntu-mate*`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'grub-theme-ubuntu-mate' for regex 'grub-theme-ubuntu-mate*'
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ubuntu-mate-core : Depends: grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

and : `sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate
The following NEW packages will be installed:
grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/87,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 146 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 420496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate_0.3.6~trusty4_all.deb ...
Unpacking grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate (0.3.6~trusty4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate_0.3.6~trusty4_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/boot/grub/themes/ubuntu-mate/background.png', which is also in package grub-theme-ubuntu-mate 0.3.3~trusty1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate_0.3.6~trusty4_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: You need to report this issue in launchpad, against the `grub-theme-ubuntu-mate` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because one package is trying to overwrite the file of other package.

So first remove the conflicting package.
 To do this open terminal and type this command

```
 sudo apt-get purge grub-theme-ubuntu-mate*
```

Once above command completed successfully execute this command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: i have update my question

Comment: Ok run `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-mate-core ` first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have dependency problems after installing mate. Try these commands and see if it helps:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo update-grub
```